# HTML Шаблонизатор webpack

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка, webpack, handlebars

Подскажите шаблонизатор HTML для webpack, использую проект вместо gulp для верстки. Нужно функционал на подобии React/Vue, только конечно же в своем синтаксисе, чтобы можно было импортировать файлы и указывать в них пропсы для рендера. Думал за handlebars, но не нашел информации как без JS файлов передать в пропсы массив (например `{{>header nav={["Home", "About", "Contacts"]} }}`. Есть ли предложения как можно это сделать ? (Pug не использую)